# Calling a child function from a parent constant object

Tags: c++

There is a simple version of my code :

```
   class Action:
        {
        int updateOK() {
            std::cout << "" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
   }
   class Attack:public Action
        {
        int updateOK() {
            std::cout << "att" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
   }
   class Def:public Action
        {
        int updateOK() {
            std::cout << "DEf" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    namespace actions
    {
        const Attack light = Attack();
        const Attack meduim = Attack();
        const Attack heavy = Attack();
        const Block block = Block();
        const Block cancelBlock = Block();
        const std::vector<Action> listAction = { light , meduim, heavy , block, cancelBlock };
    }

    Main.cpp :
    for each (Action action in actions::listAction) {
                action.updateOK();
    }
```

The issue is that it always calls the parent function in the main.

I have tried virtual functions in many ways but I want to find a solution to the problem without casts.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You need to revisit [how polymorphism works](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm)

Comment: Hint. Keyword override is your best friend here :-)

Comment: What do you mean without casts? Adding `virtual ` before parent function seems to be the way to go without major changes.

Comment: @aybassiouny Well you also need to use pointers and when you use them you will get implicit cast from the derived class to the base class pointer.

Comment: So I have to make a list of pointers like const std::vector<const Action*> listAction

Comment: @NathanOliver oh you are correct I didn't read the rest of his example. If he needs a generic container he will need to use pointers to base class as objects.

Comment: the problem is that I use const objects

Comment: which are slow to create

Comment: @MoranAbadie I don't see any way around it, yes. You will also need to make the rest such as `Action* block = new Block();`

Comment: You should also add `;` after your class definitions, this code does not compile...

Comment: @Chiel I didn't copy past sorry

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to do is Object slicing:

It happens when a derived class object is assigned to a base class object, additional attributes of a derived class object are sliced off to form the base class object

Comment: thanks I will google it ;)

Comment: if you want to achieve the desired result, use polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind casts you need to:

- Make parent function virtual for dynamic binding to work
- if you need to use a generic container you will need to use pointers to base class as objects.

Sample edits:

```
   class Action:
   {
        virtual int updateOK() {
            std::cout << "" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
   };

--- the rest of classes --- 

    namespace actions
    {
        const Action* light = new Attack();
        const Action* meduim = new Attack();
        const Action* heavy = new Attack();
        const Action* block = new Block();
        const Action* cancelBlock = new Block();
        const std::vector<Action*> listAction { light , meduim, heavy , block, cancelBlock };
    }

    Main.cpp :
    for(Action* action : actions::listAction) {
                action->updateOK();
    }
```

Comment: I tried it before but the problem is that it gave me an ` error : cannot convert from 'Action *const ' to 'Action'`